# Error Trying to Install React on Windows 10

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to install react on windows 10 using npm install -g create-react-app.

The install fails and I get the following error message:

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm''

I should mention that I installed nodejs version 12.16.3 LTS on my windows machine right before I got this error.

Does anyone know why this is, or if there's a solution to this problem?

Please help!

Comment: Can you try with -g flag?

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your comment. I did use the -g flag and unfortunately received the same error message.

Comment: Try this out, uninstall complete nodejs then try to install again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ali and I'll give that a go.

Comment: Ali, I followed through with the uninstall and reinstall of nodejs. Sorry to say I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not trying to install `react`. You are trying to install `create-react-app` terminal tool. With that tool you can easily create react projects.

Let's do some checks first.

```sh
# Remove if you have installed it before
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

# Check if you have installed 'git' (if not install git)
git --version

# Check node.js (if not install node.js)
node --version


# Check npm  (if not install npm)
npm --version
```

If they are all installed, now you can start installing create-react-app. I am not windows user but i would suggest you to use powershell. On linux i would use sudo command for this install.

```sh
# install create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app

# check if it is installed
create-react-app --version
```

Comment: Thank you Ci Boz for outlining the steps in the process. I have followed that sequence of steps, with one exception and that is uninstalling create-react-app, since I haven't been able to install it at all. The result is the same and I still cannot run the command without errors.

Comment: Ashame. I think these issues were the main reason i stop using Windows. I think windows is great for .net development but it just make it difficult for other development environments